# Question from Nov 2006 ( cambridge A-level)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've got stuck with this question (Cambridge A-level question Nov 2006 paper 3)

(first part) Simplify $$ \left( \sqrt {1+x} + \sqrt {1-x}\right)  \left( \sqrt {1+x} - \sqrt {1-x} \right) $$

(second part) showing your working, and deduce that

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt {1+x} +\sqrt {1-x}} = \frac {\sqrt {1+x}- \sqrt {1-x}}{2x} $$

Actually I succeeded in simplifying the first part and got $(1+x)-(1-x)$ but I'm stuck with the second part. We should use the result of the first part to deduce for the second part.

Comment: More generally $\frac{1}{a+b}=\frac{a-b}{a^2-b^2}$. Let $a=\sqrt{1+x}, b=\sqrt{1-x}$.

Comment: In your first expression, did you mean to *multiply* those two expressions in square brackets? Addition does not give the result you state. And if you intend to post more questions on this site you should learn to use braces $\{\}$ to enclose the contents of the square root, as in $\sqrt{1+x}$ from $\\sqrt\{1+x\}$.

Comment: Is the first part supposed to be multiplication? $$\left( \sqrt {1+x} + \sqrt {1-x}\right)\mathbf \times \left( \sqrt {1+x} - \sqrt {1-x} \right)?$$

Comment: Also, you can simplify $(1+x)-(1-x)$ further...

Comment: Yes that's right, will correct

Comment: HINT: for second part multiply the numerator and denominator with something so that the denominator looks like the question in the first part

Comment: Yes true, got the answer!!! I actually multiplied the numerator and denominator with $ (\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt {1-x} ) $ as well as using the result in the first part - the simplified one- and succeeded in showing.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify the first part $$ \left( \sqrt {1+x} + \sqrt {1-x}\right)  \left( \sqrt {1+x} - \sqrt {1-x} \right) $$ until it is equal to 2x.

Then multiply the fraction in the second part (in both numerator and denominator by
 $ (\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt {1-x} ) $

This should give the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of this like any question where you have surds, and you need to rationalise the denominator of a fraction. If you had:

$$\frac{1}{a-\sqrt{b}}$$

You would simply do:

$$\frac{1}{a-\sqrt{b}} \times \frac{a+\sqrt{b}}{a+\sqrt{b}}$$

This would simply rationalise the denominator, and you have to do a similar thing in this particular case. Firstly, you say that you got to:

$$(1+x)−(1−x)$$

Simplify that to $$2x$$
Then, start to do the second part, and rationalise its denominator:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}} \times \frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}$$

The denominator has already been worked out (always look back at previous parts of the question to see what you have already done). The denominator is $$2x$$ and the numerator is just $$\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}$$
That is your answer.